# IOS 6 How to send a static facebook message with facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook

I need to send a private message to a facebook friend via application. I have read in some links that it is not possible.

To accomplish this Iam posting to a wall using  presentFeedDialogModallywithSession which works well but is there any way to autofill the dialog as I need to post the values of a textbox to a friend..

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't autofill this dialog. Also note that this dialog will post to your wall instead of your friend's one regardless of the value of "to" field.

Comment: Yes it posts to my wall as well as to my friend.. Is there any other way to send a message to a friend on facebook from my application

Comment: No. But you could mention or tag users in your post so your friend will see it in notification center and in his timeline (if accepted). Or you can send invitations (but it might be not what you exactly want)

Comment: That seems to be a good solution but can I send a static message ie without showing a dialog to the user.

Comment: I think you can't. The Facebook tries to be as much user-friendly as possible so any hidden activities should be prohibited. Even with mentions you can't pre-define any person in your text. The user should select one by himself in order to let mentions mechanism work.